# How to provide window to library with webpack

Tags: webpack

I'm converting an app to use webpack and there's a library trying to access `window.navigator.userAgent` and it's failing with "Cannot read property 'userAgent' of undefined".  (the library is jquery.browser but I imagine it could easily come up in others)

How can I make sure a library has access to the `window` object?

I've read webpack's shimming guide, and have also familiarized myself with the `externals` configuration.  I've used imports-loader to attempt to import it, I've set `window: 'window'` in the `externals` object, I've added `window: 'window'` to ProvidePlugin, and various combinations, but with the same results.

I suppose there's a combination of configs I haven't tried yet that's the key.  Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, to answer my own question here: it seems that out of the box modules have access to `window` just fine.  The trouble with the library in question (jquery.browser) is it had a umd wrapper where the `window` variable was a local variable, which was being set via `this` being passed into a function.

So to get the local `window` variable set properly, I was able to configure webpack to set `this` to `window` using imports-loader:

```
{ test: /jquery\.browser/, loader: 'imports-loader?this=>window' }`
```